# Physical Complex Space

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, mathematics, complex-numbers

I think if there is a system of coordinates consisted of real number, there is also a system of coordinates consisted of imaginary number. But this system is not a complex coordinate. It is only consisted of imaginary number. So, I tried to create this, but failed. Can this coordinate exist? If can, Is there a physical space consisted of imaginary number?

Comment: Yes, Penrose's twistor theory is formulated in three complex dimensions and the Calabi-Yau spaces used in compactifying string theory have three complex dimensions.

Comment: This question (v3) seems too broad. For starters, we can e.g. identify a 2D plane $\mathbb{R}^2\cong \mathbb{C}$ with the set of complex numbers.